# Hitting a 401 Unauthorized error when trying to interact with on-prem sharepoint 2019 (REST API C#)

Tags: c#, rest, sharepoint, authorization, http-error

I'm trying to build out an API call that would add a new item to a already existing SharePoint list, however I keep bumping into a 401 unauthorized error. I've tried using different "levels" of admin accounts. but I'm still getting the same result.

Below is the current implemented code.

```
try
{
    using (ClientContext context = ClientContext("MyURL"))
    {
        context.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username,password,"MyDomain");
        List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Continuous Improvement Action Log");
        ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
        ListItem newItem = ContinuousImprovement.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
        newItem["Category"] = Category;
        newItem["Title"] = Title;
        newItem["Source"] = Source;
        newItem["Dept"] = Dept;
        newItem["Status"] = Status;
        newItem["Responsibility"] = Responsibility;
        newItem["DateOpen"] = DateOpen;
        newItem["TargetCompletion"] = TargetCompletion;
        newItem["Notes"] = Notes;
        newItem["ActionNotes"] = ActionNotes;
        newItem["InitiativeType"] = InitiativeType;
        newItem["TeamMember"] = TeamMember;
        newItem["InitiativeName"] = InitiativeName;
        newItem["Complete"] = Complete;
        newItem["OverdueEmail"] = OverdueEmail;
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }

    return "Success";
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return e.Message;
}
```

I'm not sure if I should be looking at the code or the settings of our SharePoint server ... any direction will be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to [create a new item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) in a list using the graph API.

Example:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "fields": {
    "Title": "Widget",
    "Color": "Purple",
    "Weight": 32
  }
}
```